# переадресация всех запросов с одного домена на другой

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, mod-rewrite

Есть новый сайт new.site.com,
есть старый сайт site.com.

Как сделать так, чтобы все http-запросы на site.com/new/
шли на new.site.com/
(в том числе обращения из .css и .js файлов) ?

Веб-сервер - Apache 2.2, OS - Linux Debian, в public_html есть файл .htaccess, вот его содержимое:

```
php_value date.timezone Europe/Moscow
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # When your application folder isn't in the system folder This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the request to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Интересуют решения на стороне веб-сервера, код приложения трогать крайне нежелательно.

Answer (score 1):

Проще некуда:

```
RewriteRule ^/new(/.*)$ http://new.site.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Вставьте сразу после

```
RewriteEngine On
```